# Airport Extreme sharing 1TB disk

Tags: airport, sharing, external-disk

I just bought an Airport Extreme thinking it was easy to share a USB disk.
I'm very disappointed that this is taking so much time and still not working.

The disk is 1TB NTFS formatted. It works well while connected directly to my MBP but via Airport Extreme I just can't get it work. Both on Mac and on Windows I can't connect, it's not discoverable. Even connecting via smb://10.0.0.1/mydisk won't work.

Is this due by the NTFS format or I'm just missing something?

Thank you

Comment: It will be best for you to do some troubleshooting yourself and reformat it to Mac OS Extended (Journaled) to see if it works.

Comment: I have the same thing but with HFS+ and FAT. It works. I just have to click on the Airport express icon on the finder sidebar.

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo You were able to have HFS+ on Windows too? I found some plugins but they are not free :(

Comment: No, on a Mac. Sorry I thought you were talking about OS X because you said MBP and never mentioned windows.

Answer (score 1):

Airport Extreme [does not support NTFS disks](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202807).

You can format your disk as FAT32 or (preferably) HFS+, a.k.a. Mac OS Extended (Journaled), and it should then be accessible to both Mac and PC clients.